# weird exception in Rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, exception

The log clrearly shows that commitment_end was posted by the user.

What am I missing ?
Should I check if commitment_end is nil before comparing it's size ?

Method:

```
  def commitment_is_in_the_future
    if commitment_end < Time.now.to_date
      errors.add(:commitment_end, I18n.t('validate_future_date'))
    end
  end
```

Log

> A NoMethodError occurred in deals#create:
>
> undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass  app/models/deal.rb:19:in`
>   commitment_is_in_the_future'
>
> ### ------------------------------- Request:
>
> - URL       : http://domain.com/deals  * IP address: 146.10.1.1  *
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>     "authenticity_token"=>"k7J6KAp+69E+zdsfs+MVRwtax39Q6m6FfNRkZRQ=",
>     "deal"=>{"company_id"=>"7", "service_id"=>"2",
>     "**commitment_end**"=>"**31-11-2011**", "price"=>"150"}, "commit"=>"done",
>     "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"deals"}  * Rails root: /app

Comment: I'm investigating this gem :
https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `attr_protected` or `attr_accessible` in your model, then the "commitment_end" value in the params might not be set in the model as `@commitment_end`. This would cause your `commitment_end` method call in the if statement to return `nil`.

Another cause could be that "commitment_end" is not an attribute of the model, and you need an `attr_accessor` in your model to have `@commitment_end` set.

Could you please post more of your model/schema related to 'commitment_end'? It may clear up where the value is/is not being set.

Comment: create_table "deals", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.integer   "company_id"
    t.integer   "commitment_monts"
    t.date      "commitment_begin"
    t.date      "commitment_end"
    t.integer   "price"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
    t.integer   "service_id"
  end

Comment: attr_accessible :user_id, :company_id,:service_id, :commitment_monts, :service, :commitment_begin, :commitment_end, :price

Should I check if commitment_end is nil before comparing it's size ?
Thanks!

Comment: Checking that it is nil would help avoid the error, but it doesn't explain why it is nil when the data is being passed into the model.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running? I just setup a dummy Rails 3.1.0 app with a Deal model with date attribute 'commitment_end', attr_accessible for :commitment_end, and before_validation :commitment_is_in_future, and I didn't encounter any problems...

Comment: 3.0.9 it doesn't happen all the time. I'm thinking I have a problem in the client side. the jquery date picker must not function properly on some browsers. "31-11-2011" is an invalid date. thanks for your help